# When I kill a subprocess created in a bash script - it automatically re-spawns. Why?

Tags: bash, kill

I have the following script which I run using the command:

```
./thescript.sh 2>&1 &
```

and if I kill the sub process spawned by it, after a few seconds it is restarted. Why is this?

thescript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

#...
#other stuff
#...

while true; do
         nohup /usr/bin/php ../thing/script.php scriptargs >my_log.log 2>&1
        /bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "me@home.com" < $EMAILMESSAGE
done
```

the result of

```
     ps -ax | grep scriptargs
```

gives

```
19624 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./thescript.sh
19643 pts/0    S      0:00 /usr/bin/php ../thing/script.php scriptargs
19771 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep scriptargs
```

if I run

```
kill 19643
```

I get:

```
./thescript.sh: line 24: 19643 Terminated /usr/bin/php ../thing/script.php scriptargs >my_log.log 2>&1
```

but if then run:

```
     ps -ax | grep scriptargs
```

again I get:

```
19624 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/bash ./thescript.sh
19824 pts/0    S      0:00 /usr/bin/php ../thing/script.php scriptargs
19862 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep scriptargs
```

I get the email - but then it respawns that process.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be because of the loop

```
while true; do

done
```

When the process gets killed, it exits and allows the mail to be sent. The shell then hits the `done` statement and loops back the the `while true` which is erm true so it runs the commands within, again.

Comment: In other words: You kill just the sub-process so the main script keeps looping around the while and starts the script again. You will have to kill both the main process and the sub-process.

Comment: so I don't actually need a loop. The parent script will await the execution of the sub script.

Comment: @Stevo: Yes, if that's what you want.

Comment: Cool - that's aided my understanding. I should have started my comment  with a D'Oh!